# SQL Server - Different WHERE's clauses to different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to specify different where's clauses to different columns, for example, for my "PrinterCounter.EndPagesColor" and "PrinterCounter.EndPagesMono" I want to use this where:

```
WHERE 
    PrinterCounter.ReadTime >= '01/07/2017 00:00:01' 
    AND PrinterCounter.ReadTime <= '31/07/2017 23:59:59' 
    AND Printer.WasRemoved = 0 
    AND ClientId = 6 
    AND SubClientId = 752
ORDER BY 
    PrinterCounter.ReadTime DESC
```

but for "PrinterCounter.StartPagesColor" and "PrinterCounter.StartPagesMono" i want this one:

```
WHERE 
    PrinterCounter.ReadTime >= '01/07/2017 00:00:01' AND   
    PrinterCounter.ReadTime <= '31/07/2017 23:59:59' AND
    Printer.WasRemoved = 0 AND
    ClientId = 6 AND
    SubClientId = 752
ORDER BY 
    PrinterCounter.ReadTime ASC
```

Here's the full code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Printer.[PrinterId],
    Printer.[PlaceId],
    PrinterCounter.ReadTime,
    PrinterCounter.EndPagesColor,
    PrinterCounter.EndPagesMono,
    PrinterCounter.StartPagesColor,
    PrinterCounter.StartPagesMono
FROM    
    [~client_database~].[dbo].[Printers] AS Printer
JOIN 
    [~system_database~].[dbo].[PrinterCounter] AS PrinterCounter ON PrinterCounter.PrinterId = Printer.PrinterId
WHERE 
    PrinterCounter.ReadTime >= '01/07/2017 00:00:01' 
    AND PrinterCounter.ReadTime <= '31/07/2017 23:59:59' 
    AND Printer.WasRemoved = 0 
    AND ClientId = 6 
    AND SubClientId = 752
ORDER BY 
    PrinterCounter.ReadTime ASC
```

I'll make it clear for you, every printer has a counter in the start of the day and one at the end of the day, the production will be the end minus the start.

Each client has several printers and i have to collect the production every single printer in the period of time provided.

That join is to ensure that the SQL only returns printers with counters.

---

This is what a want:

```
SELECT
DISTINCT
    Printer.PrinterId
    ,Printer.PlaceId
    ,PrinterCounter.ReadTime
    ,(
        SELECT TOP 1
            EndPagesMono 
        FROM 
            [system_mfpm].[dbo].[PrinterCounter]
        WHERE
            PrinterCounter.ReadTime >= '01/07/2017 00:00:01' AND PrinterCounter.ReadTime <= '31/07/2017 23:59:59'
            AND PrinterCounter.ClientId = 6
            AND PrinterCounter.SubClientId = 752
            AND PrinterCounter.PrinterId = Printer.PrinterId
        ORDER BY PrinterCounter.ReadTime DESC
    )-(
        SELECT TOP 1
            StartPagesMono 
        FROM 
            [system_mfpm].[dbo].[PrinterCounter]
        WHERE
            PrinterCounter.ReadTime >= '01/07/2017 00:00:01' AND PrinterCounter.ReadTime <= '31/07/2017 23:59:59'
            AND PrinterCounter.ClientId = 6
            AND PrinterCounter.SubClientId = 752
            AND PrinterCounter.PrinterId = Printer.PrinterId
        ORDER BY PrinterCounter.ReadTime ASC
    ) AS Mono
    ,(
        SELECT TOP 1
            EndPagesColor
        FROM 
            [system_mfpm].[dbo].[PrinterCounter]
        WHERE
            PrinterCounter.ReadTime >= '01/07/2017 00:00:01' AND PrinterCounter.ReadTime <= '31/07/2017 23:59:59'
            AND PrinterCounter.ClientId = 6
            AND PrinterCounter.SubClientId = 752
            AND PrinterCounter.PrinterId = Printer.PrinterId
        ORDER BY PrinterCounter.ReadTime DESC
    )-(
        SELECT TOP 1
            StartPagesColor 
        FROM 
            [system_mfpm].[dbo].[PrinterCounter]
        WHERE
            PrinterCounter.ReadTime >= '01/07/2017 00:00:01' AND PrinterCounter.ReadTime <= '31/07/2017 23:59:59'
            AND PrinterCounter.ClientId = 6
            AND PrinterCounter.SubClientId = 752
            AND PrinterCounter.PrinterId = Printer.PrinterId
        ORDER BY PrinterCounter.ReadTime ASC
    ) AS Color                                                           
    FROM [client_lfn_MTUXNJCZMJQA].[dbo].[Printers] AS Printer 
    JOIN [system_mfpm].[dbo].[PrinterCounter] AS PrinterCounter ON PrinterCounter.PrinterId = Printer.PrinterId 
    WHERE Printer.WasRemoved = 0
```

but i'm pretty sure that is a bad practice and it can be improved

Comment: aren't these two `WHERE` clauses identical ?

Comment: The only difference I see is the `ORDER BY` direction

Comment: Could you do 2 separate queries and use `Union`?

Comment: I think `PrinterCounter` contains only `PagesColor` and `PagesMono` , and he want to make these columns with a condition . @OP Conditional aggregation can solve this for you.

Comment: This makes no sense what so ever.

Comment: Having written a lot of queries based around printer meters in the past, I would probably do a subquery to find a `MAX` meter and another to find the `MIN` meter, then join them to the printer info on the equipment ID.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I understood you, though i'm not sure what so ever.

If `PrinterCounter.EndPagesColor`, `PrinterCounter.EndPagesMono`, `printerCounter.StartPagesColor`, `PrinterCounter.StartPagesMono` are new columns you want to make, then you can use conditional aggregation with `CASE EXPRESSION` , it will look something like this:

```
SELECT 
    Printer.[PrinterId],
    Printer.[PlaceId],
    PrinterCounter.ReadTime,
    MAX(CASE WHEN <Your first conditions> THEN PrinterCounter.PagesColor END) as StartPagesColor,
    MAX(CASE WHEN <Your first conditions> THEN PrinterCounter.PagesMono END) as StartMonoColor,     
    MAX(CASE WHEN <Your second conditions> THEN PrinterCounter.PagesColor END) as EndPagesColor,
    MAX(CASE WHEN <Your second conditions> THEN PrinterCounter.PagesMono END) as EndMonoColor     
FROM ... // rest of query
GROUP BY Printer.[PrinterId],
         Printer.[PlaceId],
         PrinterCounter.ReadTime
```

Though I think you also need to remove `ReadTime` column from the select list.